# How can i check product is purchased in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, in-app, mkstorekit

I have 3 subscription. now I have bought 1 subscription in my signup screen using my itunes email id but now I open once again signup then i want to check which product is purchased using same itunes email. If any product is purchased  then I want open my new view. How can I check which product is purchased in view did load method?

Please help

Comment: You have to check the in app purchase receipt. Refer to the in app purchasing programming guide

Comment: can i get itunes email id? @Paulw11

Comment: how can i work with receipt. can you get reference ?

Comment: Receipt returns perticular itunes user? @Paulw11

Comment: @Paulw11 I got Receipt response but it got all purchase responses for particular device. I want to know  purchase of purticular itunes user becz of 1 user can buy only 1 subscription.if user is bought any subscription then i want to open my view

Comment: The receipt is all you have.  It will tell you the purchases that were made on that device (or on other devices with the same iTunes ID)

Comment: Perhaps you could explain more clearly what you are trying to do and why the receipt doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: I need to get which product id purchase for same itunes user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142583/discussion-between-paulw11-and-maulik).

Answer (score 0):

when your purchase occurs, then Apple returns the receipt corresponding to that product ID
OR

you can use that as well to save in userdefault like this as i am doing:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
```

And where ever u need to check for purchase then access value from userDefault :

```
BOOL check3 =  [_stdDefaults valueForKey:InApp_Effects];
```

Comment: can I get itunes email id?

Comment: Receipt returns perticular itunes user?

Comment: You can't get the iTunes id for privacy reasons. If you have a userid associated with your app, you can submit it with the purchase request to help Apple detect suspicious activity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004616/ios-auto-renewable-subscriptions-questions-regarding-the-renewing-process